# When initialize action trigger?

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I am using redux-form 5.3. When server side validation reject error. Initialize action overwrites errors

Comment: You will have to provide some code. There is no reason for the INITIALIZE action to be dispatched just for clicking on a field.

Comment: I find where is problem, but i cannot sure how to solve it. This is not my project, in there the form data is stored in intermediate `state.order.form` . and when initialize action trigger it passses values to initialValues. Problem is that when error occurs this data not be saved in `state.order.form`. And intialize return it without errors. Currently solved it by saveing this error in state when error catched.